# how to fix Method not found Exception:onRowSelect(SelectEvent event)?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am getting the following error when I select a row in the lazy datatable :

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Method not found: com.gestion.projet.web.jsf.ProjetComponentImpl@f632823.onRowSelect(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and then the code associated with the following bean method:

```
@Scope("session")
@Component("ProjetComponent")
public class ProjetComponentImpl implements ProjetComponent {
    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Projet Selected", ((Projet) event.getObject()).getIdprojet().toString());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
}
```

and this the xhtml page:

```
<h:form id="form">
            <p:dataTable var="current" value="#{ProjetComponent.lazyModel}"  
                paginator="true" rows="10" 
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{ProjetComponent.projet}" id="projetTable" lazy="true">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{ProjetComponent.onRowSelect}"
                    update=":form:projetDetail" oncomplete="PF('projetDialog').show()" />
                <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{current.idprojet}" filterBy="#{current.idprojet}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{current.idprojet}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Nom" sortBy="#{current.nomprojet}"
                    filterBy="#{current.nomprojet}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{current.nomprojet}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog header="Projet Detail" widgetVar="projetDialog" modal="true"
                showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                <p:outputPanel id="projetDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2"
                        rendered="#{not empty ProjetComponent.projet}"
                        columnClasses="label,value">
                        <f:facet name="header">

                        </f:facet>

                        <h:outputText value="Id:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{ProjetComponent.projet.idprojet}" />

                        <h:outputText value="Nom:" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{ProjetComponent.projet.nomprojet}" />

                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

this is a snaphshot of what i get when i select a row :
[image]

Comment: Is your Impl a Component or a Bean? your annotations are likely incorrect @ SessionScoped and @ ManagedBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're interchanging Spring Annotations with JSF annotations - PrimeFaces is a JSF component library in use with a JSF Managed Bean - `@SessionScope` and `@ManagedBean(name="projectBlah")`

from the javax.faces.bean packages

Comment: but im using spring with jsf

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/ however it doesn't use annotations seems. You need to separate the controller imply from your beans sorry . Haven't tried t. Use spring with jsf yet :)